# AMD Radeon VCE init error (-22) on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, 16.04, radeon, amd-graphics

Everything is running well, I don't have any problems with booting/playing games, but this disquites me.

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep -E '(drm)|(radeon)'
[    3.337655] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    3.387697] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
[    3.397808] fb: switching to radeondrmfb from EFI VGA
[    3.398209] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (ARUBA 0x1002:0x9903 0x17AA:0x3804).
[    3.398223] [drm] register mmio base: 0xF0300000
[    3.398225] [drm] register mmio size: 262144
[    3.398230] [drm] ACPI VFCT contains a BIOS for 00:01.0 1002:9903, size 19968
[    3.398340] radeon 0000:00:01.0: VRAM: 768M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000002FFFFFFF (768M used)
[    3.398343] radeon 0000:00:01.0: GTT: 1024M 0x0000000030000000 - 0x000000006FFFFFFF
[    3.398346] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=768M, BAR=256M
[    3.398347] [drm] RAM width 32bits DDR
[    3.398447] [drm] radeon: 768M of VRAM memory ready
[    3.398449] [drm] radeon: 1024M of GTT memory ready.
[    3.398472] [drm] Loading ARUBA Microcode
[    3.398544] [drm] Internal thermal controller without fan control
[    3.398720] [drm] radeon: dpm initialized
[    3.400703] [drm] Found VCE firmware/feedback version 50.0.1 / 17!
[    3.400719] [drm] GART: num cpu pages 262144, num gpu pages 262144
[    3.423915] [drm] PCIE GART of 1024M enabled (table at 0x00000000002E8000).
[    3.424060] radeon 0000:00:01.0: WB enabled
[    3.424065] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000030000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff88012863dc00
[    3.424824] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x0000000000075a18 and cpu addr 0xffffc90001435a18
[    3.444880] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 6 use gpu addr 0x0000000030000c18 and cpu addr 0xffff88012863dc18
[    3.444886] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 7 use gpu addr 0x0000000030000c1c and cpu addr 0xffff88012863dc1c
[    3.444889] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000030000c04 and cpu addr 0xffff88012863dc04
[    3.444893] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000030000c08 and cpu addr 0xffff88012863dc08
[    3.444896] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000030000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff88012863dc0c
[    3.444899] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000030000c10 and cpu addr 0xffff88012863dc10
[    3.444978] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    3.444981] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    3.444986] radeon 0000:00:01.0: radeon: MSI limited to 32-bit
[    3.445268] radeon 0000:00:01.0: radeon: using MSI.
[    3.445635] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
[    3.465125] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 2 usecs
[    3.465134] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 3 usecs
[    3.465141] [drm] ring test on 4 succeeded in 3 usecs
[    3.510932] [drm] ring test on 5 succeeded in 1 usecs
[    3.530848] [drm] UVD initialized successfully.
[    3.640228] [drm] ring test on 6 succeeded in 15 usecs
[    3.640239] [drm] ring test on 7 succeeded in 2 usecs
[    3.640241] [drm] VCE initialized successfully.
[    3.641273] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    3.641814] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    3.642385] [drm] ib test on ring 4 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    3.662903] [drm] ib test on ring 5 succeeded
[    4.179529] [drm] ib test on ring 6 succeeded
[    4.180128] [drm] ib test on ring 7 succeeded
[    4.184523] [drm] radeon atom DIG backlight initialized
[    4.184528] [drm] Radeon Display Connectors
[    4.184530] [drm] Connector 0:
[    4.184532] [drm]   eDP-1
[    4.184534] [drm]   HPD1
[    4.184536] [drm]   DDC: 0x6530 0x6530 0x6534 0x6534 0x6538 0x6538 0x653c 0x653c
[    4.184538] [drm]   Encoders:
[    4.184540] [drm]     LCD1: INTERNAL_UNIPHY2
[    4.184542] [drm] Connector 1:
[    4.184543] [drm]   VGA-1
[    4.184544] [drm]   HPD2
[    4.184547] [drm]   DDC: 0x6540 0x6540 0x6544 0x6544 0x6548 0x6548 0x654c 0x654c
[    4.184548] [drm]   Encoders:
[    4.184549] [drm]     CRT1: INTERNAL_UNIPHY2
[    4.184551] [drm]     CRT1: NUTMEG
[    4.184552] [drm] Connector 2:
[    4.184553] [drm]   HDMI-A-1
[    4.184555] [drm]   HPD3
[    4.184557] [drm]   DDC: 0x6550 0x6550 0x6554 0x6554 0x6558 0x6558 0x655c 0x655c
[    4.184558] [drm]   Encoders:
[    4.184560] [drm]     DFP1: INTERNAL_UNIPHY
[    5.395703] [drm] fb mappable at 0xD04EC000
[    5.395708] [drm] vram apper at 0xD0000000
[    5.395710] [drm] size 4325376
[    5.395712] [drm] fb depth is 24
[    5.395714] [drm]    pitch is 5632
[    5.395904] fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    5.396045] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device
[    5.407948] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.43.0 20080528 for 0000:00:01.0 on minor 0
[    5.408171] radeon 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    5.408554] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (HAINAN 0x1002:0x6663 0x17AA:0x3804).
[    5.408568] [drm] register mmio base: 0xF0200000
[    5.408570] [drm] register mmio size: 262144
[    5.466510] [drm] GPU not posted. posting now...
[    5.470260] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VRAM: 2048M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000007FFFFFFF (2048M used)
[    5.470264] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GTT: 1024M 0x0000000080000000 - 0x00000000BFFFFFFF
[    5.470267] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=2048M, BAR=256M
[    5.470269] [drm] RAM width 64bits DDR
[    5.470286] [drm] radeon: 2048M of VRAM memory ready
[    5.470289] [drm] radeon: 1024M of GTT memory ready.
[    5.470311] [drm] Loading hainan Microcode
[    5.470497] [drm] Internal thermal controller without fan control
[    5.470595] [drm] probing gen 2 caps for device 1022:1412 = 700d01/6
[    5.480053] [drm] radeon: dpm initialized
[    5.480060] [drm] GART: num cpu pages 262144, num gpu pages 262144
[    5.481570] [drm] probing gen 2 caps for device 1022:1412 = 700d01/6
[    5.481577] [drm] enabling PCIE gen 2 link speeds, disable with radeon.pcie_gen2=0
[    5.824949] [drm] PCIE GART of 1024M enabled (table at 0x0000000000040000).
[    5.825088] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[    5.825093] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff88003461dc00
[    5.825097] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c04 and cpu addr 0xffff88003461dc04
[    5.825100] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c08 and cpu addr 0xffff88003461dc08
[    5.825104] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff88003461dc0c
[    5.825107] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c10 and cpu addr 0xffff88003461dc10
[    5.825110] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VCE init error (-22).
[    5.825114] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    5.825116] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    5.825119] radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: MSI limited to 32-bit
[    5.825227] radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: using MSI.
[    5.825266] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
[    6.035647] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 1 usecs
[    6.035656] [drm] ring test on 1 succeeded in 1 usecs
[    6.035663] [drm] ring test on 2 succeeded in 1 usecs
[    6.035672] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 3 usecs
[    6.035679] [drm] ring test on 4 succeeded in 3 usecs
[    6.036445] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    6.036509] [drm] ib test on ring 1 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    6.036547] [drm] ib test on ring 2 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    6.036586] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    6.036614] [drm] ib test on ring 4 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    6.037806] [drm] Radeon Display Connectors
[    6.040326] [drm:radeon_acpi_init [radeon]] *ERROR* Cannot find a backlight controller
[    6.040503] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.43.0 20080528 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
[   18.658736] [drm] probing gen 2 caps for device 1022:1412 = 700d01/6
[   18.658743] [drm] enabling PCIE gen 2 link speeds, disable with radeon.pcie_gen2=0
[   19.002323] [drm] PCIE GART of 1024M enabled (table at 0x0000000000040000).
[   19.002446] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[   19.002451] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff88003461dc00
[   19.002456] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c04 and cpu addr 0xffff88003461dc04
[   19.002459] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c08 and cpu addr 0xffff88003461dc08
[   19.002463] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff88003461dc0c
[   19.002466] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c10 and cpu addr 0xffff88003461dc10
[   19.002469] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VCE init error (-22).
[   19.211262] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 1 usecs
[   19.211269] [drm] ring test on 1 succeeded in 1 usecs
[   19.211276] [drm] ring test on 2 succeeded in 1 usecs
[   19.211285] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 3 usecs
[   19.211292] [drm] ring test on 4 succeeded in 3 usecs
[   19.211351] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   19.211541] [drm] ib test on ring 1 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   19.211609] [drm] ib test on ring 2 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   19.211628] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   19.211643] [drm] ib test on ring 4 succeeded in 0 usecs

$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Complex
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity [Radeon HD 7640G]
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity HDMI Audio Controller
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Port
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Port
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Port
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 09)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 16)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 5
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun PRO [Radeon HD 8570A/8570M] (rev ff)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet (rev 10)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)


$ uname -a
Linux dot-pc 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 3):

The driver is attempting to initialize VCE on a card that does not support it. The message is totally harmless - just ignore it.