# Radeon vce init error at startup

Tags: boot, 16.04, drivers, radeon, amd-graphics

I am having an error message when my laptop boots saying

> radeon vce init error

I would really appreciate any suggestions to help me know what it means and how should I go about fixing it?
I am also attaching something that might be useful although I've no clue as to what it means. Thanks in advance.

```
 version: ubuntu 16.04 LTS

raxit@ubuntuPrime:~$ sudo lspci -vnk | grep -iA20 vga

[sudo] password for raxit: 

00:02.0 0300: 8086:1916 (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

    Subsystem: 103c:81ec
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 6000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] #1b
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] #13
    Kernel driver in use: i915_bpo
    Kernel modules: i915_bpo

00:04.0 1180: 8086:1903 (rev 08)

    Subsystem: 103c:81ec
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at b1420000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]

raxit@ubuntuPrime:~$ dmesg | egrep -i 'vce|error'

[    0.229547] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC failed (AE_ERROR); disabling ASPM


[    1.328354] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VCE init error (-22).


[   95.206948] EXT4-fs (dm-1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro

[   96.245913] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VCE init error (-22).

[  105.255744] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VCE init error (-22).

[  114.069001] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VCE init error (-22).

[11188.476030] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915_bpo]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=671790 end=671791) time 358 us, min 1073, max 1079, scanline start 1063, end 1088

raxit@ubuntuPrime:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntuPrime 4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: me too. my friend has this error

Answer (score 0):

I saw this link [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768567/amd-radeon-vce-init-error-22-on-ubuntu-16-04)
Looks like it is a duplicate answer.  Looks harmless according to the author.  Maybe install proprietary drivers?