# Upgrade: solve dependency on previous release package

Tags: package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I just upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04. This wasn't easy, probably because I had a lot of tweaks on my machine (updated packages not installed from "official" sources). It wouldn't boot, I thought at first it was a graphics card problem ("[Radeon init error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768567/)"), but eventually made it boot by downloading (on other machine) `libstdc++6` then installing with `dpkg -i`, using Grub root shell 
(similar problem [as the one here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777803/)).

I am now able to boot, have the desktop session. Fine.

Now the problem: I have a heavy package dependency problem, all the `apt-get` commands will fail. Consider this:

```
$ sudo apt-get check
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libstdc++-5-dev : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~14.04) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10 is installed
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) but 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~14.04 is installed
              Breaks: libogre-1.8.0 (<= 1.8.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but 1.8.1+dfsg-0ubuntu3 is installed
 libstdc++6:i386 : Depends: gcc-5-base:i386 (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) but 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~14.04 is installed
                   Breaks: libogre-1.8.0 (<= 1.8.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5) but 1.8.1+dfsg-0ubuntu3 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

The given advice (`apt-get -f install`) does nothing.

As you can see, what is strange is that there seems to be a mixup of packages from 14.04 and 16.04:

- `libstdc++-5-dev` depends on the 14.04 version of `libstdc++6`, and I have of course the 16.04 version intalled.
- `libstdc++6` depends on a 16.04 package (`gcc-5-base`) but I seem to **still have a 14.04 version**!!!

I tried to reinstall the 3 packages with:

```
sudo apt-get -f install <pkgname> --reinstall
```

=> unable

I tried to remove libstdc++-5-dev with:

```
sudo apt-get -f remove libstdc++-5-dev
```

=> it asks for unmet dependencies of several other packages. If I remove them one by one, I end up at the same point.

I also tried a lot of other things but basically end up at the same point.

Other info:

```
$ lsb_release -ir 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Release:    16.04
$ uname -m
x86_64
```

**Question:** how do I get myself out of this dependency problem?

Comment: Where did the `libstdc++6` that you installed to fix the boot problem come from?

Comment: Thanks, just fixed the issue. I came from the official repo, as given here: https://askubuntu.com/a/792471/69802

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved, thank to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/835918/) and [its answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/870051/69802) 
(didn't find it at first as the title isn't very explicit, thus I don't withdraw my question, as it might be useful for others).

So, just in case, the solution is:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
```

(and of course after that: `apt-get upgrade` and `apt autoremove`to finalize).

Comment: Same identical problem here and your solution worked like a charm!

Comment: thank men, Same identical problem here

Answer (score 1):

I had this unmet dependency error. Using Software Updater I installed recommended GCC, GNU C Compiler, GNU C++ Compiler after that I couldn't even restart and get to the login screen. After reading like every solution for two days which none of them worked for me, I combined 2 of them to be able to finally fix the problem.

1- Changed the sources in /etc/apt/sources.list file with the default ones I found here :
https://gist.github.com/rohitrawat/60a04e6ebe4a9ec1203eac3a11d4afc1

```
sudo leafpad /etc/apt/sources.list
```

(I use leafpad you can use any other text editor if you prefer)

2- I have learned that aptitude is better at dealing with dependency issues, so I run this command to install gcc

```
sudo aptitude install gcc
```

3- Then aptitude suggested me a solution to fix the problem which is a very long list to uninstall crucial packages like arandr, ubuntu-desktop etc. therefore I pressed **n** and didn't accept the first suggestion, but accepted the second suggestion as follows:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

Upgrade the following packages:                                           

1)      gcc-5-base [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12 (now, xenial-updates) -> 5.5.0-12ubu
2)      libstdc++6 [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12 (now, xenial-updates) -> 9.3.0-10ubu

      Downgrade the following packages:                                         
3)      gcc-9-base [9.3.0-11ubuntu0~14.04 (now) -> 9.3.0-10ubuntu2~16.04 (xenial
4)      gcc-9-base:i386 [9.3.0-11ubuntu0~14.04 (now) -> 9.3.0-10ubuntu2~16.04 (x
5)      libatomic1 [9.3.0-11ubuntu0~14.04 (now) -> 9.3.0-10ubuntu2~16.04 (xenial
6)      libcc1-0 [9.3.0-11ubuntu0~14.04 (now) -> 9.3.0-10ubuntu2~16.04 (xenial)]
7)      libgcc1 [1:9.3.0-11ubuntu0~14.04 (now) -> 1:9.3.0-10ubuntu2~16.04 (xenia
8)      libgcc1:i386 [1:9.3.0-11ubuntu0~14.04 (now) -> 1:9.3.0-10ubuntu2~16.04 (
9)      libgomp1 [9.3.0-11ubuntu0~14.04 (now) -> 9.3.0-10ubuntu2~16.04 (xenial)]
10)     libitm1 [9.3.0-11ubuntu0~14.04 (now) -> 9.3.0-10ubuntu2~16.04 (xenial)] 
11)     liblsan0 [9.3.0-11ubuntu0~14.04 (now) -> 9.3.0-10ubuntu2~16.04 (xenial)]
12)     libobjc4 [9.3.0-11ubuntu0~14.04 (now) -> 9.3.0-10ubuntu2~16.04 (xenial)]
13)     libquadmath0 [9.3.0-11ubuntu0~14.04 (now) -> 9.3.0-10ubuntu2~16.04 (xeni
14)     libtsan0 [9.3.0-11ubuntu0~14.04 (now) -> 9.3.0-10ubuntu2~16.04 (xenial)]

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] **Y**
```

and the problem is gone.