# Ubuntu 16.04: gcc-5-base broken

Tags: package-management, dependencies, gcc

On Ubuntu 16.04 I've problems with **gcc-5-base** package:

```
user@laptop:~$ sudo apt install libgfortran3
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgfortran3 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) but 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

No hold packages: `dpkg --get-selection | grep hold` returns nothing.

No automatic fixes to apply:

```
user@laptop:~$ sudo apt -f install
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Reinstall says that everything is ok (but of course is not):

```
user@laptop:~$ sudo apt install gcc-5-base
gcc-5-base is already the newest version (5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

No dependencies to clean:

```
user@laptop:~$ sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded
```

I think that the problem arose upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04: I've used [these commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067814/upgrade-solve-dependency-on-previous-release-package/1067833#1067833) to fix libstdc++, after `do-release-upgrade`.

Any other hints?

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like an outdated package list; have you run `apt update` recently?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention: `sudo apt update` returns `All packages are up to date`. No issue with repositories at all. And I don't have PPAs.

Comment: You definitely have an issue with your repositories, because Apt wants to install version `5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04` of `gcc-5-base` despite its not being the latest version (the latest version is `5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11`). Maybe `apt-cache policy gcc-5-base` could give a hint...

Comment: Your command reports `gcc-5-base:
  Installed: 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04
  Candidate: 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04
  Version table:
 *** 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
     5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.3.1-14ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages`

Comment: Further info: `dpkg --get-selections | grep deinstall` returns nothing as well.

Comment: The problem is that you have this `5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04` version installed, and it's not clear where it's coming from (it's not from the official repos). You could try reverting to the correct one with `sudo apt install gcc-5-base=5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11`, but if you have other packages that depend on the 5.5 version, they would need to be reverted as well.

Comment: Ok, how could you say that the official one is 5.4.0 instead of 5.5.0? Because in synaptic I see that only 5.5.0 is available and the latest one...and if I run your command i get `E: Version '5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04' for 'gcc-5-base' was not found`

Comment: You didn't copy the command correctly (it's `16.04.11`). ;) You can see in the `apt-cache policy` output that version `5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04` does not correspond to any repository. The reason why it appears is that it's installed, but it's unclear where you got it from.

Comment: You are right @fkraiem, thank you for pointing it out. I solved with this discussion, I will post it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using `sudo apt install gcc-5-base=5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11`. That removed a lot of things, also a critical package to me: `xubuntu-desktop`.

But reinstalling it with `sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop` solved other broken dependencies and I was able to do `sudo install libgfortran3` with success.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package gcc-5-base

Answer (score 0):

From the problem description, the issue is completely clear.

Your issue is:

libgfortran3 is what you wish to install.
     =>=> but it requires gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11)
     .. .. ..=>=> But gcc-5-base (5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04) is available.

See, the problem is, to install libgfortran3 you need (exactly, because of = sign)  5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11, but this version is not available. What IS available is: 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04, which cannot satisfy the dependency (because the condition is exact match). So nothing is installed.

And since nothing  has been, your installation base is also correct, and in correct state. But the package IS broken.

**Solution**

First download the deb of libgfortran3

```
 sudo apt download libgfortran3
 sudo dpkg -i --force-depends libgfortran [your version] .deb
```

The first will download the libgfortan3-*version*.deb to your pwd.

Next, modify /var/lib/dpkg/status to make dpkg shut up.

```
 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

- edit /var/lib/dpkg/status
- Find the package with the broken dependencies
- edit the Depends: line to stop the package complaining.

Find the line:

```
Package: libgfortan3
```

Next edit the line Depends (a few line after the previous one)

Modify:

```
Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11)
```

To:

```
Depends: gcc-5-base (>= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11)
```

That should fix it.

Comment: This answer is nonsense.

Comment: That worked! The only thing that remains to solve is that `apt update` returns 1 package to upgrade and `apt list --upgradable -a` returns libgfortran3, but `apt upgrade` returns nothing.

Comment: I used a cleaner solution reported above. Thank you anyway Domo N Car!